# How to set AudioChannel as Left Headphone and Right headphone?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audio-recording, audiobuffer

I am using playing audio as soon as we received any input from microphone. I am using **OSStatus** for recording and playing audio. As the recording and playing are working fine.

I have to active left side headphone, right side headphone or center as per user select. As I research  **AudioBuffer**, we have to set **mNumberChannels** for left, right and center headphone. Here is my code for playing audio.

```
    AudioBuffer buffer;

//    // 1 - Left
//    // 2 - Right
//    // 3 - Center
//    
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 0;


    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2;
    buffer.mData = malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 );

    // Put buffer in a AudioBufferList
    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;

    // Obtain recorded samples

    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioUnitRender([iosAudio audioUnit], 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             &bufferList);
    checkStatus(status);



    // Now, we have the samples we just read sitting in buffers in bufferList
    // Process the new data
    [audioProcess processAudio:&bufferList];

    free(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData);

    return noErr;
```

But I am not able to enable left, right or center if I changed **mNumberChannels**. Can anyone help to point out my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The correct value **mNumberChannels** for an AudioBuffer can be derived from the mChannelsPerFrame and the interleaved flag. For non interleaved formats, mNumberChannels is always 1. For interleaved formats, **mNumberChannels** is equal to mChannelsPerFrame.

So **mNumberChannels** is for specifying the number of channels in the processing buffers, NOT for *panning* or routing audio to "left"-"center"-"right". So setting it left=1, right=2, center=3 is wrong.

After recording into the audiobuffer, to do *panning* (selecting audio playback via left/center/right), you should connect your current processing unit to a Multichannel Mixer unit (subtype *kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer*) which takes any number of mono or stereo streams and combines them into a single stereo output and supports stereo *panning* for each input.

With this mixer unit, you can use a property like [kMultiChannelMixerParam_Pan](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitParametersReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kMultiChannelMixerParam_Pan), to control left/center/right.